# Subtracting from values ending with specific digits?

Tags: awk, sed

I have a .bed (.tsv) file that looks like this:

```
chr1    0   100000
chr1    100000  200000
chr1    200000  300000
chr1    300000  425234
```

I want to perform the operation -1 from only values in column 3 that end in "000", using sed or awk so that the output looks like:

```
chr1    0   99999
chr1    100000  199999
chr1    200000  299999
chr1    300000  425234
```

Embarassingly enough, the best I've come up with is:

```
awk {sub(/000$/,"999",$3); print $1,$2,$3}' oldfile > newfile
```

which simply substituites the last 3 digits for 999, rather than actually subtracting.
Any help is appreciated is always!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Awk can easily perform arithmetic, too.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} $3 ~ /000$/ {$3 -= 1}1' oldfile > newfile
```

This is assuming all the lines in your file always have three fields and that you want to print all the lines.

`sed` has no idea about even the simplest arithmetic so it's not particularly suitable for this.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the edit, I always manage to shoot myself in the foot by forgetting about `OFS`.

Comment: Yeah, it's a common mistake. In a perfect world `-F` would set both FS (which would also be renamed IFS) and OFS but - that's not going to happen now we're 40 years down the line...

Answer (score 0):

I would use GNU `AWK` for this as follows, let `file.txt` content be

```
chr1    0   100000
chr1    100000  200000
chr1    200000  300000
chr1    300000  425234
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}($3%1000==0){$3-=1}{print}' file.txt
```

output

```
chr1    0   99999
chr1    100000  199999
chr1    200000  299999
chr1    300000  425234
```

Explanation: Use tab (`\t`) as output field separator (`OFS`). If remainder from diving `$3` by `1000` is zero (i.e. `$3` is multiply of `1000`) then subtract `1` from `$3`, for each line `print`.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: The result of `$3%1000` is a floating point number (see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Arbitrary-Precision-Arithmetic) so I wonder if that's guaranteed to always be exactly equal to zero given input that's a multiple of 1000. I really don't know.